# Disable VPN DNS server and take over with dnsmasq

Tags: networking, vpn, dns

I have a local network setup using **dnsmasq** as my DNS server. I assigned domain ***.home** to my local devices, so I make it more user-friendly for other house members. I have following entry in my dnsmasq config file `address=/minipc.home/10.10.10.2`

All the subdomains are being handled with a reverse proxy. This works perfectly!

The problem is when I use my VPN (**Tailscale**) which is not aware of my local DNS mapping. There is an option to disable Tailscale DNS and let my dnsmasq take over. Could you help me reproduce this https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/issues/3980?

I already tried adding `server=/100.100.100.100/ts.net` to **dnsmasq** config file to resolve the Tailscale requests. That unfortunately didn't work. I also tried adding `nameserver 100.100.100.100` as the upstream nameserver in **/etc/resolv.conf**, but without success.

What am I missing here?